# German or Czech town (or city)

Tags: germany, historical-gazetteer, czechoslovakia

I have a document issued during 1940's by German authorities which shows my great-grandfather's place of birth. I am trying to determine where the place is. The town or city in either Germany or the Czech Republic (formerly in the Austrio-Hungarian Empire) called "Auscher" or "Anscher". I don't speak German and I couldn't find any such city. Does the name look familiar to anybody?

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This seems to say "Auscha," which is indeed the German name of a town known in Czech as [Úštěk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9A%C5%A1t%C4%9Bk).

Comment: yes this is Úštěk which is a bit of a mouthful to pronounce. These communities were mixed.